# Iterate through distinct value with nested sum

Tags: sql-server

I'm using MS SQL Server.  I have a single table called 'Commissions' that contains customer, date, category, and commission amount.   I'm trying to get a customer count by category.

I've figured out the SQL code that gives me a total customer count for a single category.

```
declare @category nvarchar(50)
set @category = 'Shirts'

select @category , COUNT(*) 
from (
SELECT     SUM(Commission) AS CommTotal, [Real Customer]  
FROM         dbo.Commissions
WHERE     category = @category and ([Line Item Date] >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-10-01', 102) AND [Line Item Date] < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-10-01', 102))
GROUP BY [Real Customer]
) as Agg
```

The output of this code produces

Shirts    652

What I would like to do next is to do the equivalent of adding a wrapper around this code, that would give me a customer count of all 5 of the categories.

```
'-- wrapper  
select distinct category from commissions
```

- Shirts    652
- Pants     1420
- Shoes     342
- Socks     553
- Hats      992

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please provide, sqlfiddle with the schema?.

Comment: did you try to put category in group by and then in inner selecction and out select, and forget category variable?.

Comment: I've never used sqlfiddle, so it may take me a little while to put it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: In your code you are selecting by a single category. In your output example you want all categories. So the selection has to be removed.

Second: I am assuming that the combination of customer and category is not unique but you want a customer only to be counted once per category.

Third: I am copying your date selection.

You need to group by category and then count the number of customers per group counting each customer just once.

Try this:

```
select category, count(distinct [Real Customer])
from Commissions
where ([Line Item Date] >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-10-01', 102) 
and [Line Item Date] < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-10-01', 102))
group by Category
```

Albert

Comment: Thank you Albert !   It works great.   I appreciate the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query. It will count the number of distinct values of `[Real Customer]` for each category.

```
SELECT category, COUNT(DISTINCT [Real Customer]) 
FROM dbo.Commissions
WHERE [Line Item Date] >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-10-01', 102) AND [Line Item Date] < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-10-01', 102)
GROUP BY category
```

You can also optionally add a `where` clause to limit the number of categories, if you want, to those that you listed. Or leave the query as above to get all categories.